# Getting data from required columns from two Tables

Tags: sql

I need to create a view that queries data from two tables:

- Table #1 as `Project` (contains columns `ProjectID`, `Resource1`, `Resource2`, `Resource3`, `Resource4` etc.)
- Table #2 as `ResourceTable` (contains columns `ResourceID`, `AccountNO` etc.)

I need to query the `AcccountNo` for four resources based on `ProjectID`.

Like

```
ProjectID, AccountNO for Resource1, AccountNO for Resource2, AccountNO for Resource3, AccountNO for Resource4
```

For this I created following query - but it only returns data for one resource:

```
SELECT
    [ProjectID], [AccountNO]   
FROM 
    [dbo].[Project] 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[ResourceTable] ON [ProjectID].[ResourceID1] = [dbo].[ResourceTable].[AccountNO ]
```

Output:

```
ProjectID   AccountNoforResource1
----------------------------------
08SMA0001   NULL
10DL0051    29608529
10DL0052    NULL
10DL0053    NULL
10DL0055    29608233
10DL0058    29608233
11DL0011    NULL
11DL0013    29608233
```

but I need all resource account numbers..

Please help me resolve this..

Thanks..

Comment: I think.. You need to add ProjectID in your second Table...

Comment: It seems that your design is poor. why is `Project` table having separate columns for `resources`. what if there is `5th` resource?

Comment: Also kindly share sample data and desired output.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you typed it twice, I'll assume that `[AccountNO ]` (with the space) is the actual column name, if so that's a bit weird, but OK!

Try the query below.  Also note how I've [aliased](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) the tables using the `as` keyword: `p`, `r1`, `r2`, and so on.  The `as` keyword is entirely optional (I usually leave it out but added it for clarity):

```
select [ProjectID], 
    r1.[AccountNO ] as [AccountNO_1],
    r2.[AccountNO ] as [AccountNO_2],
    r3.[AccountNO ] as [AccountNO_3],
    r4.[AccountNO ] as [AccountNO_4],
from [dbo].[Project] as p
left join [dbo].[ResourceTable] as r1 on p.[ResourceID1] = r1.[ResourceID]
left join [dbo].[ResourceTable] as r2 on p.[ResourceID2] = r2.[ResourceID]
left join [dbo].[ResourceTable] as r3 on p.[ResourceID3] = r3.[ResourceID]
left join [dbo].[ResourceTable] as r4 on p.[ResourceID4] = r4.[ResourceID]
```